# Pandas: getting a different behavior when doing .loc with list of features or with slice of features

Tags: pandas

I noticed that I'm getting a different behavior when using .loc of pandas...

When using a slice for selecting columns: `X_train = df.loc[:, 'col_0':'col_n']` no issue

But when using: `X_train = df.loc[:, features]` where `featuers` is the list of features I used in the slice in above example ('col_0', ...to... ,'col_n') I'm getting:

> KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['col_0', 'col_1', 'col_2'], dtype='object')

**Note**: col_0, col_1, col_2 where inserted to the df

I had tried to reindex or reset index but it didn't help!

Another weird behavior, that the features importance (of My machine learning model) is different when using the different .loc methods!

What can be the issue? Is there a difference between both methods?

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the missing labels

Use [`columns.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.intersection(features)]
```

Or, if you want to add the missing labels:

```
df.reindex(columns=features)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.... it worked. But what causes it?

Comment: As I said, it comes from missing labels. Why you have missing labels is a question I cannot answer to ;)